# How to repeat capture before a caracter for replacement

Tags: regex, replace, regex-group

I spent my last two days to find a regex that replace every dots before the left parenthesis by underscores.

The expression is :

```
name.of.the.film.(year).codec.quality. ... .extension
```

where  :

- `(year)` match `\((\d){4}\)`
- `name.of.the.film.` match `([^.]+\.)+` (could be `name.of.` or `name.of.the.film.name.of.the.film.` )

I tried `^(([^.]+(\.))+)\(` I'm able to capture the last point before the parenthesis, because, as far as I understand, repeating a capture only keep the last match. But how to capture every dot match.

[EDIT]
As mentioned below in comments, several left parenthesis can occur in the expression. I have to replace dots before the **first** left parenthesis.

Comment: Try [`\.(?=[^(]*\(\d{4}\))`](https://regex101.com/r/UdccXK/1). If there are two `(year)`s, it will also replace those dots before each (year). What is the regex flavor here? Where are using the regex?

Comment: Well, I have to rename file on gnu/linux OS via a bash script. I think I'll use `sed -E`.

Comment: Then both solutions won't work. You should use perl to make these patterns work. Please add a `sed`  tag to get a solution for `sed`.

Comment: If I have to use perl, then I will use perl (even if I never wrote a line of perl in my life). Sed is a great tool but it many times trouble me with regex.

Comment: Well, you currently accepted an answer that does not do the job correctly. Try [`sed` solution like `sed -E ':a;s/\.([^(]*\([0-9]{4}\))/_\1/;ta'`](https://ideone.com/UfUC1w). If you think it works better for you than the currently accepted solution, I will post for you to accept.

Comment: I can pipe perl in my bash script `| perl -p -e 's/[.](?=.*\(\d{4})/_/g;'`. Then both works for me. Can I promote two solutions in Stackoverflow  ?`Anyway, many thanks you helped me a lot.

Comment: Ok, just shorten it to `-pe` (`-p -e` => `-pe`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match what you are looking for:

```
/[.](?=.*\()/g
```

A dot, followed by a positive lookahead of any character string terminating with open parenthesis.

Demo with replacement: https://regex101.com/r/PEur1t/1

EDIT: if there are multiple occurrences of strings in parenthesis, this may not give the expected results, as it will replace every dot up to the very last open parenthesis. Because it would be very unlikely to successfully understand which one is the desired one without any other assumptions, I am now assuming the year will be a four digit string:

```
/[.](?=.*\(\d{4})/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PEur1t/2

Comment: Yes it works but I don't understand why !!  Why does this match every dot while the regex is greedy ? It should match only the first dot and the positive lookahead match everything until the parenthesis.

Comment: @user9428517 Does it really work? What if you have `name.of.the.film.(2018).codec.quality. ..(5).extension`. It will replace all dots before `(5)`. This `[.](?=.*\()` regex is "unsafe" in that regard.

Comment: @user9428517 Since it's a lookahead, it just ensures the dot is followed by a parenthesis somewhere on the rest of the string. Since it does not capture it, the greedy part doesn't really matter in this case (a `.*?` might be more performant though, as it would make sure the lookahead stops looking when it encounters the first parenthesis).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good point I didn't consider the possible presence of more parenthesis; it just replaces every dot until the the last one

Comment: A lazy `.*?` does not necessarily work faster (it won't if the `(` is very close to the end of the string and the dots are close to the start). Actually, there is no need comparing efficiency here since the strings are small.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, your answers made my day! I did learn a lot.